# authorize.net sandbox testing errors "The merchant does not accept this type of credit card"

Tags: testing, credit-card, authorize.net

I am using the testing guide (http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/)  to test on the authorize.net sandbox environment. The visa and mastercard and jcb card numbers were successful, but american express, discover, and diners club cards failed:  "Transaction Error : 17 The merchant does not accept this type of credit card."

Why would the test environment not accept those cards, or it something else?  Please advise.

Thanks

(my code used the sample code from: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/ChargeCreditCard.cs)

Comment: Are you *sure* you are in a test environment?

Comment: I am using sandbox credentials, and the code logged in my console prior to the error : "Retreiving Response from Url: 'https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api'" .. that look right?

Answer (score 0):

If  your sandbox account is not configured for a particular card, use the contact [us form](http://developer.authorize.net/support/contact_us/) to request the card brands you want added.